# Hardhat script - Error: No Contract deployed with name NftMarketplace

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am following the Patrick Collins tutorial
for the [hardhat-nft-marketplace](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-nft-marketplace-fcc).
I am running a hardhat script with the terminal command:
`yarn hardhat run scripts/mint-and-list.js`

And I am getting the following error:

```
$ /Users/johndoe/local/hardhat-fcc-course/hardhat-nft-marketplace-fcc/node_modules/.bin/hardhat run scripts/mint-and-list.js
Error: No Contract deployed with name NftMarketplace
    at Object.getContract (/Users/johndoe/local/hardhat-fcc-course/hardhat-nft-marketplace-fcc/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:447:11)
    at mintAndList (/Users/johndoe/local/hardhat-fcc-course/hardhat-nft-marketplace-fcc/scripts/mint-and-list.js:6:28)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

For the below script:
**mint-and-list.js**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const PRICE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")

async function mintAndList() {
    const nftMarketplace = await ethers.getContract("NftMarketplace")
    // console.log(nftMarketplace.address)
    const basicNft = await ethers.getContract("BasicNft")
    // console.log(basicNft.address)
    console.log("Minting...")
    const mintTx = await basicNft.mintNft()
    const mintTxReceipt = await mintTx.wait(1)
    const tokenId = mintTxReceipt.events[0].args.tokenId
    console.log("Approving Nft...")

    const approvalTx = await basicNft.approve(nftMarketplace.address, tokenId)
    await approvalTx.wait(1)
    console.log("Listing Nft...")
    const tx = await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, tokenId, PRICE)
    await tx.wait(1)
    console.log("Listed!")
}

mintAndList()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

Here are the deploy scripts:

**01-deploy-nft-marketplace.js**

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config.js")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    log("----------------------------")
    const args = []
    const nftMarketplace = await deploy("NftMarketplace", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    // const nftMarketplace = await deploy("NftMarketplace", deployer)

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(nftMarketplace.address, args)
    }

    log("----------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "nftmarketplace"]
```

**02-deploy-basic-nft.js**

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config.js")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    log("----------------------------")
    const args = []
    const basicNft = await deploy("BasicNft", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(basicNft.address, args)
    }

    log("----------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "basicnft"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found out that this can be resolved by simply specifying the network `--network localhost` and hence running this command in the terminal:

```
yarn hardhat run scripts/mint-and-list.js --network localhost
```